# web browsing from unix and it's automation

Tags: shell-script, webserver

I wanted to know about the scope of web browsing through unix . I went through the following questions :

[Is there a way to use curl interactively? Or is there an interactive curl/wget shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51944/is-there-a-way-to-use-curl-interactively-or-is-there-an-interactive-curl-wget-s)

[Automating web requests using curl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/automating-web-requests-using-curl)

and some more posts and questions like the above mentioned two questions .

I have tried to use `curl` and `wget` to fetch responses from web-pages in solaris. But have not yet investigated the possibility of simulating  mouse clicks and filling forms through unix. The above questions inform of a handful of commands and libraries to do so but since nothing has been said specifically about the possibility to do so from unix so I could not assure myself .

So I would like to know if the ideas mentioned in the above questions like `perl mechanise` and `libwww`, `lynk` or `curl` (in interactive mode) can also be used for Unix (solaris ,specifically).

If yes,would you suggest some scripts that I can learn from  ?

Comment: You should be aware that those tools are not so much "simulating mouse clicks and filling forms" as going a bit deeper: they are tools for creating HTTP(S) GET, HEAD and POST (and other) requests, either manually or controlled by scripts.  As a result, some familiarity on what happens between the web server and the browser at the technical level is required to use those tools effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in those question answers ties you to a Linux platform. If you have the applications installed on Solaris they'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Asking on

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Would be more appropriate but there are already answers such as

https://askubuntu.com/questions/29540/browsing-the-internet-from-the-command-line