# command to download & agree licensed software

Tags: command-line, wget

I am writing a script that download [this](https://software.intel.com/protected-download/739797/493768) software, then install and run it on linux system.

Issue is when I do `wget` to download, my download doesn't initiate, it halts showing below line, because software web portal waiting user to accept license terms&conditions:

```
Connecting to software.intel.com
```

I can download this software from my windows system, since I can accept license agreement by clicking accept button. But how do I download this software and accept license agreement from my linux system in script?

Do I need to pass any parameter in wget command?

Comment: See [this answer on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/161814/498780) , install Export cookies [from here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies-txt/)

Answer (score 0):

`wget` is [non-interactive](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget). If you wish to interactively download via the shell you will need to use [different software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51944/is-there-a-way-to-use-curl-interactively-or-is-there-an-interactive-curl-wget-s).

To get your package, the easiest course of action would be to accept the license and download it on a computer with a browser than using `scp` or `sftp` or any other method to transfer files from one computer to another.

In the end you cannot interactively download using only `wget`, you would have to wrap it in a interactive script or use a different method to obtain this package.

Comment: I am not able to wget even with the download link you shared. Reason you're able to do so, I am guessing, is that you already accept license agreement, and that is saved for your that session. If you simply open incongnito mode of any browser and try copy-pasting your link, it will not download file.

Comment: @ghost204nit I see what you mean. the file I downloaded was not a valid tarball. Is it at all possible to simply download this file on one computer with a browser and push the tarball over to the machine that needs it? Is there any other way that Intel distributes these kinds of files? I am going to edit the answer to remove that part as it is invalid.

Comment: @kemotop: scp or sftp option I was already aware of, but was reluctant to use, as I wanted to have complete automation. I did not find any other way that Intel distributes this package. So now, for sake of simplicity and time efficiency, I am going with scp.

Comment: @ghost204nit Part of the issue is that you have to navigate multiple pages and the download links are based on cookie sessions so you will need to contact Intel to see if they have API for this on their site. If you do not need to change packages very often you only need to get your hands on this package once manually and you could automate the deployment of it to many machines.